# Deserializing nested objects without LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson

My problem is that I have a json string with nested objects and Jackson uses `LinkedHashMap` when deserializing them. How do you configure Jackson so it prefers `HashMap` type when constructing the objects?

`mapper.readValue("{\"a\":\"b\":\"nes\"}", Map.class)`

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help: [link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/85)

Comment: It would be relatively complicated to change that default, plugging in your own `DeserializerFactory` that selects `HashMap` as a fallback Map type but keeps all the other logic the same. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using `graaljs` with java interop which doesnt play well with linkedhashmap unfortunately :(

Comment: Do you know how many levels of inner `JSON Object` do you have?

Comment: No unfortunately @MichałZiober

Comment: In that case there is no way to force `HashMap` for all levels. We could implement some kind of workaround if you would know a number of levels. Internal implementation could be different from version to version, which version of `Jackson` do you use? From another side, you probably would have to recreate root `Map` and internal `Map` instances and convert them to `HashMap` after deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no configuration for it. However, you can write custom Deserializer for `Map.class`. Something like that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Map.class, new JsonDeserializer<Map<?,?>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<?,?> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            return jsonParser.getCodec()
                    .readValue(jsonParser, HashMap.class);
        }
    });
mapper.registerModule(module);
final Map<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue("{\"a\": {\"b\":1}}", Map.class);
assertEquals(HashMap.class, map.get("a").getClass());
```

I don't think that it will work as you wish, however, maybe it will help you in research.